# Puppet lookup for server facts

Tags: puppet, lookup

What extra configuration is required to ensure puppet lookup considers server facts?

If I have code in the catalog for a particular node which makes use of server_facts, such as

notice($server_facts['environment')

Catalog compilation for puppet agent -t will work perfectly.

However a puppet lookup query of

puppet lookup --compile --node nodename module::keyname

For any particular key, will fail, as the catalog will fail to compile (due to the absence of the server facts)

What additional configuration is required so that the catalog compilation triggered by puppet lookup includes server facts?

Tried a lookup for a node which uses server facts in its catalog
Expected the lookup to succeed

Comment: I'm surprised that you're having trouble, but I can't speak to why without a [mre].  Be sure to include the exact text of the error message (though that alone is not enough).  As a preliminary, though, do you actually need `--compile` for your particular lookup purposes in the first place?  That would be a bit unusual, and if you don't need it then the question is moot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.